# Can an action-state or decision-state be the start-state in a webflow application?

Tags: spring-webflow

I am a newbie to Spring Web Flow. I am going through couple of examples in tutorials. Can an action-state or decision-state be the start-state? What is the difference between this and view-state being the start-state?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, either `<action-state>` or `<decision-state>` (which is just a special case of `<action-state>`) can be the starting state.

The difference is simply whether you have any code to run or decisions to make when the flow begins, or whether the very first thing a user does is view a starting page.

We often use one of these "logic" type starting states in conjunction with an [`<input>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.4.7.RELEASE/reference/html/defining-flows.html#input-element) element passed in to start the flow.